# write javascript to page based on a condition

Tags: php, javascript

I need to remove some Javascript code based on a server side condition (PHP). What I currently have is a variable holding the Javascript code as text and based on the condition I either echo it or not. However, it's cumbersome to maintain. How do I go about doing it?

I also tried to use something like what follows, but it's not working.

```
<?php if(condition) { ?> <script> stuff here </script> <?php } ?>
```

I'm sorry for the formatting, I have no idea why the less-then sign is making the entire line disappear.

Comment: That approach should work OK. But there are two other errors in that line: no `?` before `php` and no `$` before condition. If it's just formatting - fix it, but if it's in your coe - that is a source of the problem

Comment: @J0HN, it was a formatting error. Thanks for the fix.

Comment: Why theis is not working? You are getting PHP errors, or JS is just not working? If you open "Source View" (Ctrl+U in FF and Chrome, if I'm not mistaking), do you see your script where it should be?

Comment: @J0HN no errors at all. When I Source View the javascript code is found on the page which means the code is not working properly.

Comment: Try replacing condition with false, and tell us if that works.

Comment: Than it means that the error is in your JS, not in PHP. Maybe you copy-pasted it from your former php variable and left some escape sequences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to do something like this:

```
<?php
  if ($something) {
?>
<script>
  alert('hi')
</script>
<?php
  }
?>
```

Comment: This is not working at all ;(. The script tag is always showing. Is there anything that I should take into consideration?

Answer (score 0):

Besides including it in a variable and outputting it conditionally, the only other possibility that I can think of is to put the JavaScript code in a file, and then have a PHP condition which outputs an include for that JavaScript file if it is true.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work?

```
<?php if(condition){ ?>
    <script> ... </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: `condition` should be `$condition`, eh?

Comment: so is it `CONDITION` or `condition` ? :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
define('condition', true);
if(condition) { ?> <script> stuff here </script> <?php } ?>
```

should work

Comment: sorry, the condition is just something I wrote to denote there is a condition here, not a constant. I messed the formatting pretty badly.

Comment: it doesn't matter, if condition is true, it's outputed

Answer (score 0):

what about hiding or showing the // comment lines with php?

```
if ($something){
echo "//"; ?>   <script> 
<?php
echo "//"; ?>     alert('hi') 
<?php
echo "//"; ?>   </script> 
<?php
```

}